# Representing json array of unknown dimensions in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4",
    },
    {
        "key1": "value5",
        "key2": "value6",
        "key3": "value7",
        "key4": "value8",
    }
]
```

Is it possible to create a table without knowing the number of keys? Something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="key in keys">
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="value in values">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in keyObj">{{col}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="key in keys">
            <td ng-repeat="col in key"> {{col}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.keys = [
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4",
    },
    {
        "key1": "value5",
        "key2": "value6",
        "key3": "value7",
        "key4": "value8",
    }];

    $scope.keyObj = Object.keys($scope.keys[0]);
});
```

Working sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/X9ibqnsSXCPBgmcOBih0)

Comment: Note: this is just an sample, not an error proof. You may have to handle the no data scenarios before assigning the keyObj

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the answer formatted in another way? So you don't have `key.key1` or `key.key2`. I would format the JSON response as following:

```
[
    keys:[
        1:"key1",
        2:"key2",
        3:"key3",
        4:"key4"
    ],
    values: [
     1: [
            "value5",
            "value6",
            "value7",
            "value8"
        ],
     2: [
            "", "", "", ""
        ]
    ]
]
```

Anyway, I would try to avoid custom json fields in views since they may change in the future.